# HTTP 403 No Assertions Found

Tags: apache, http

Hibernate/Glassfish application with CAS login.  Testing new version of CAS.  Getting this error - what does it mean?

HTTP Status 403 - no assertions found

Access to the specified resource (No assertions found.) has been forbidden.

The server bean does log a record showing that the user has logged in, so we get that far, but we're unable to display the initial page.

I found this entry in the Apache log. Other items in the log generally have a code 200 after them.

GET "/myBean/myPage.faces HTTP/1.1" 302 287

Comment: It could be a permission problem, did you check file and folder?

Comment: Pretty close! It turned out to be an issue with old Glassfish cached files.  Glassfish isn't very helpful about deleting these files.